# Java - Months and days?

Tags: java, time

First of, I have been searching to find anything close to my question but I couldn't find anything. I am not a very good programmer, I have just started to play with it a little, and my interest for it is growing a lot.

I was thinking if I could make a basic program with basic and easy understandable language, to a month and days "calculator".

Like if I have a sysout print which says: `Write month number`, and I'll type in `11`, and then write a day number in the month and someone writes `27` it will say date correct!

But if it asks me for month and I'll type `6`, as `June` and I write in `31` as days it will print which would say `Month 6 doesn't have day 31`.

I want to keep it simple so I understand like basic language not too hard! I'm just a fresh starter!

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Sorry mate, I couldn't stand all those typos - edited lot of them.

Comment: Haha! Thanks for fixing it, I have been figuering how to write this program for a while now, I have seem to loose my ability to type.

Comment: This is the code I have written I know its awful.
public class Date {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("write in month number :");
    int  month;
        month = 7;    
        if (month <1 ) {
        if (month >12){
        }
         
            System.out.println("month "" has no such day");
       } 
 }
}

Comment: If doing real work rather than homework or practice, know that this behavior is largely implemented in the [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to get the job done, I'd suggest you go have a look at the [Calendar API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or perhaps [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

If you're more interested in *learning* how to do it yourself, here's one suggestion for an approach:

Hard-code an array like

```
int[] daysInMonths = { 31, 27, 31, ... };
```

and then check using something along the following lines:

```
// Get month and day from user
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int month = s.nextInt();
int day = s.nextInt();

int monthIndex = month - 1;     // since array indices are 0-based

if (1 <= day && day <= daysInMonths[monthIndex])
    print ok
else
    print does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

This program should get you going...

```
import java.util.*;

class Date {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] days = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
        System.out.print("Enter a month number and a day number (separate using \';\':_");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(";");
        int month = sc.nextInt();
        int day = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        System.out.println((day == days[month - 1]) ? "Date correct!" : "Date incorrect: Month " + month + " does not have day " + day);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest changing from BufferedReader to Scanner.

Comment: @aioobe OK, but is there a specific reason?

Comment: Shorter lines, better readability, 1 line instead of 9 (!) for reading an integer.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, Im ashamed that I still dont understand the basics.  Im trying to run your code but I cant seem to get it to work running. Your class Date, is it something I should change since my class name is something diffrent and im getting erros on some lines, can you try running it? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Sebastian Which lines are causing errors? I ran it and didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

in Date class, the first month January is "0", ZERO. So you think June and you write 6, but must be 5; as

```
January 0
February 1
March 2
April 3
May 4
June 5
```

Comment: Me too. It is always confusing... And now we have Calendar, that makes everything more simpler and also complex and confusing :)

Comment: it is an important point to remember, but the user can still input `6` for June, it is the program that must convert it to the correct internal number.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging the functionality of the Calendar class is a far better way to do this.

```
    int day = 31;
    int month = 6; // JULY

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(month < calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH) 
            || month > calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH))
        System.out.println("Error - invalid month");
    else 
    {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        if (day <  calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) 
                || day > calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
        {
            System.out.println("Error - invalid day for month");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Date is correct");
        }
    }
}
```

All you have to be aware of is that Calendar *currently* treats January as month 0.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Month.of( 6 ).maxLength()
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old `Date`/`Calendar` classes.

Use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

```
Month month = Month.of( 6 ) ;  // Months numbered sanely, 1-12 for January-December.
if( dayOfMonthInput > month.maxLength() ) {
    … bad input
}
```

Of course for February the last day of month depends on leap year. So if you want to be precise you need to use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2017 , 2 ) ;
if( dayOfMonthInput > ym.lengthOfMonth() ) {
    … bad input
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).